# ploting and save multiple functions in the same file matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save 6 graphs in one page using matplotlib. The graphs are each a call of a a function and came up with this code below to test before saving it:

```
def save_plot (output_DF, path = None):
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    sub1 = fig.add_subplot(321)
    plt.plot(plot_BA(output_DF))
    sub2 = fig.add_subplot(322)
    sub2.plot(plot_merchantableVol(output_DF))
    sub3 = fig.add_subplot(323)
    sub3.plot(plot_topHeight(output_DF))
    sub4 = fig.add_subplot(324)
    sub4.plot(plot_GrTotVol(output_DF))
    sub5 = fig.add_subplot(325)
    sub5.plot(plot_SC(output_DF))
    sub6 = fig.add_subplot(326)
    sub6.plot(plot_N(output_DF))
    plt.show()
```

The way it is, I do create a page with 6 empty plots, but also create 6 separate plots for every function I call. plot_BA(output_DF), for example, is a function that I call to read a csv file and create a plot (individually it is working). The other are similar functions and are working as well. It seems that I am missing something to put the graphs in their designated place of fig.

here is one of the functions I am using.

```
def  plot_BA(output_DF):
    BA =  output_DF.loc[:,['BA_Aw','BA_Sw', 'BA_Sb','BA_Pl']]    
    BAPlot = BA.plot()
    plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('BA (m2)')
    return True
```

Any tips?

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? This works for me (at least if plot_X returns an array each. You should not be plotting inside this function).

Comment: plot_X is returning a plot. I will paste its code in the main question

Comment: Okay... you have to add the argument subplot_ax to your functions (and call these with sub1, sub2, ...). Then use subplot_ax.plot() inside your functions. The same for xlabel and co. but the name's of these functions may be different then (google object-oriented usage of matplotlib). And you should not call savefig inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def function_to_call(func_name, ax):
    data = range(10)
    random_x_label = random.choice('abcdefghijk')
    random_y_label = random.choice('abcdefghijk')
    random.shuffle(data)  # demonstration

    ax.plot(data)
    ax.set_xlabel(random_x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(random_y_label)
    ax.set_title(func_name)


fig = plt.figure(1)
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(321)
function_to_call('call_0', sub1)
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(322)
function_to_call('call_1', sub2)
sub3 = fig.add_subplot(323)
function_to_call('call_2', sub3)
sub4 = fig.add_subplot(324)
function_to_call('call_3', sub4)
sub5 = fig.add_subplot(325)
function_to_call('call_4', sub5)
sub6 = fig.add_subplot(326)
function_to_call('call_5', sub6)
plt.tight_layout()  # just to improve spacings
plt.show()
fig.savefig('output_plot.png')
```

The idea is to **forward your axes-object** (which is one of many inside the whole figure) to your functions. Then you would need the axes-level functions. Notice the difference between `plt.xlabel` (**figure-level**) and `ax.set_xlabel` (**axes-level**).

[image]

Comment: My main problem here is that each figure share the same x-axis range but not the y-axis. In other words, I must consider each graph as a unique plot and not a repetition of the same plot

Comment: And what's the problem then? Just pust x and y into ax.plot(x, y). It would only get more interesting if you want to share some axes between plots.